# Disadvantages of interface objected programming

Tags: interface, parameters, extends

```
class Person{
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String gender;
    //......
}
class Student extends Person{
    private String id;
    private String schoolBelongTo;
    //......
}


public void showInfoOf(Person person){
    System.out.println(person.getName());
    //......
}
```

When using function "showInfoOf" ,if an object of Peron is used as the param,OK.However,if it is the type Student,I cannot get access to the field id and schoolBelongTo.
So I am confused ,how to ?
Actually, I want to know is this one of its(Interface oriented programming's or Supper class oriented programming's) disadvantages???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. You can programatically **check the type** in `showInfoOf (Person)`, and use a cast to access & print the desired fields;  or,
2. You can define a method on Person which will print/provide the desired info -- and either replace `showPersonInfo()` with that entirely, or call it into it. This is the more OO way.

Example:

```
abstract class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String gender;

    public void printInfo() {
        System.out.println( name);
    }
}
class Student extends Person{
    private String id;
    private String schoolBelongTo;

    @Override
    public void printInfo() {
        super.printInfo();
        System.out.println( id);
        System.out.println( schoolBelongTo);
    }
}


public void showInfoOf (Person person){
    person.printInfo();
}
```

In this example, all functionality has moved to `Person.printInfo()` and there is no real functionality remaining in `showInfoOf (Person)`.

However in the real-world, you'd probably want move versatility in a `Person.provideInfo()` function -- perhaps returning a LinkedHashMap of fields & values (since unlabelled values on their own, are not great design).

The `showInfoOf (Person)` function could then handle formatting & printing the values to the specific requirement, leaving the `Person.provideInfo()` function general & multi-purpose.

Comment: As for solution 1,It is ok,but too boring to do so. As for 2,every class provois a method sounds good.

Comment: Solution 2 is often better, because it can take advantage of inheritance & places the behaviour near the field declarations, where it can be seen & kept up-to-date easily.

Comment: As for solution 1,It is ok,but too boring to do so. As for 2,every class provides a method ,that sounds a good idea.Finally,I may use <T>.See "public <T> void showInfoOf(T t){//Print info of t}"

Comment: You don't need generics to do this -- just a superclass or interface type. Generics are for lists & collections, or where parameter/ result types of methods are interlinked.

Comment: Thank you very much.I've learnt a lot .Now I am an internal in Pactera working for expedia.I have to learn more offical programming concept and improve my oral English .You all are so kind!

Answer (score 0):

in showInfoOf() you would have to check that person is of type Student, then cast it as a Student to get id or schoolBelongsTo

Comment: Thank you. Is this one of its(Interface oriented programming's or Supper class oriented programming's) disadvantages?